# .order_by() isn't working how it should / how I expect it to

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I am using `Product.objects.all().order_by('order')` in a view, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

This is it's output:

Product Name 
            Sort 
         
     

     

             
                Evolution 
                2 
             

             
                Polarity 
                1 
             

             
                Jumbulaya 
                3 
             

             
                Kalidascope 
                4

It should look like this:

Product Name 
            Sort 
         
     

     
         
                Polarity 
                1 
            

             
                Evolution 
                2 
             



             
                Jumbulaya 
                3 
             

             
                Kalidascope 
                4

But it doesn't. Any ideas?

My view (for that output):

```
def debug(request):
    order = Product.objects.all().order_by('order')
    return render_to_response('cms/debug.html', {'order' : order, 'name' : name})
```

And the view responsible for saving the order field:

```
def manage_all(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    PostEntries = len(request.POST)
    x = 1       
    while x < PostEntries:
        p = Product.objects.get(pk=x)
        p.order = int(request.POST.get(str(x),''))
        print "Itr: " + str(x)
        x = x + 1
    p.save()
    print "Product Order saved"     
    return HttpResponse("Saved")
```

And the model (without the boring bits):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True
```

Here is a 'live' example of the page http://massiveatom.com:8080/debug/ Please note that that is only running on the dev server, so it may not always be up.

I have asked in #django and they didn't seem to know what was going on. One thought was that the database/Django was being confused by the SQL command it is generating (`select * from table where 1 order by 'order'`), but I would prefer not to change the order field in the model.

And I know there should be back-ticks surrounding order in the above SQL command, but the syntax parsing thingy kinda hated on it...

**Edit:** Each object has the correct value, so I don't really know why it isn't sorting it properly.

**Edit 2:** I don't know what was going on, but it turns out putting p.save() in the loop fixed it all...

Comment: When you look into database by yourself is order correct?

Comment: Try to run query, then try to run same queryset in django shell and see the results.

Comment: @joshhunt: When the save was outside of the loop, only last Product object (with greatest pk) was saved. If you change a field of a Django object, but forget to save it, the changes will be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your saving loop is wrong. You save Product outside of the loop. It should be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    PostEntries = len(request.POST)
    x = 1           
    while x < PostEntries:
            p = Product.objects.get(pk=x)
            p.order = int(request.POST.get(str(x),''))
            print "Itr: " + str(x)
            x = x + 1
            p.save() # NOTE HERE <- saving in loop instead of outside
    print "Product Order saved"             
    return HttpResponse("Saved")
```